# Why should you remain committed to a principle if it succeeded in the past, but not if you know not its efficacy?

Tags: utilitarianism, john-stuart-mill

<sub>CAUTION: Please edit this question's title, which I probably miswrote as I do not understand the quote below.

Source: pp 49-50, *Philosophy ; A Very Short Introduction* (2002) by Edward Craig.</sub>

> So how comfortably does the ideal of integrity fit with Mill’s
>   utilitarianism? Not very comfortably at all, some think.
>
> [1.] For however
>   sincere your commitment to some principle in the past, *THAT FACT* by
>   itself does not give you – if we take Mill’s position seriously and
>   literally – any reason to follow it again now.
>
> [2.] If in the past your
>   commitment to that principle has consistently led to good effects
>   (measured in terms of happiness), then *THAT FACT* gives you at least some
>   reason to think that it will do so again – which *IS* a reason to follow it
>   now.
>
> [3.] But your commitment to it, however sincere, however much it has become a part of your personality, is not.
>
> Critics of Utilitarianism
>   question whether we can really live with that way of thinking.

Please contrast and explain more clearly 1 vs 2? I do not see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple really. The fact that you *followed* a principle in the past is not a reason to follow it again. The fact that you *followed* a principle in the past *and* it gave good results, that is a reason to follow it again.

"We always did it this way". "Sure, we always did, and it never worked". Would you follow a principle that you used in the past and that never led to success?